# How do I activate emulation in the Coddeblocks Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-uno, emulation

I stumbled upon [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/61/can-i-program-for-arduino-without-having-a-real-board) question here, so I tried the Codeblocks alternative. After opening an Arduino Project, and leaving all options to default, I ran the Arduino version of the Hello World. A popup opened that requests a serial port to move on. What error did I do?

If more details are needed I'll answer the comments. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A serial port seems like a reasonable thing to ask for, are you sure it was in error?

Comment: Because it was an emulator rather than an launcher.

Answer (score 1):

I have not done extensive testing with the simulator but here is what you do open code blocks start a new project. Then under the target choose simulator. See the picture for details. [image: Image of Code Blocks]

I just tested it out for the simple program but this looks pretty cool.