# Arduino uno simulation software for windows

Tags: simulator

Could anyone help me for a good free arduino uno simulation software for windows.Hope I get an answer.

Comment: See [Can I program for Arduino without having a real board?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/61/can-i-program-for-arduino-without-having-a-real-board)

Answer (score -1):

Autodesk offers a service called 123D Circuits which works in a web browser provided you have an Autodesk account. It allows you to construct (simple) virtual circuits and run code on a virtual Arduino Uno. Regrettably, it doesn't offer very much in the way of diagnostics tools, isn't open source, and won't work offline. The advantage of a service like this is that it requires no installation and is functional for simple setups with a few components. It can be found at [123d.circuits.io](http://123d.circuits.io)

Comment: Thank you for that but Could you suggest me anything offline.

Comment: Can you please expand your answer? There is no link to anything (not that we want link-only answers) and nothing explains what "works in browser" means.

Comment: 123d.circuits.io is the web address. Works in browser means it works in a modern web browser like Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox. The answer has been edited to reflect this.

Comment: Indeed. Currently this answer will be useless if the service goes down. Please add more detail to make the answer useful even without the link.