# Arduino Simulator for Windows that can be detected by Arduino IDE through a Virtual COM Port

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, simulator

Hello is there an Arduino Simulator for Windows that can be detected by Arduino IDE through a Virtual COM Port?

I've seen simulator online but I can't seem to find a simulator that can be programmed using the Arduino IDE through a Virtual COM port.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I program for Arduino without having a real board?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/61/can-i-program-for-arduino-without-having-a-real-board)

Answer (score 2):

One of the option is using Proteus simulator with [Arduino library](http://www.electronicslovers.com/2015/03/how-to-add-arduino-library-in-to.html). You can build the program via Arduino IDE, then export the compiled binary (.hex file). Proteus also provided virtual terminal feature (not Virtual COM).