# Can I emulate Arduino in a headless CI/CD setup?

Tags: testing, automatization

6 years ago, there has been a question "[How to emulate Arduino on PC](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/61/can-i-program-for-arduino-without-having-a-real-board)".

Since then, probably many more Arduino emulators have been introduces.

With this question, I would like to narrow the search scope down to the following criteria:

- Linux compatible
- headless operation mode without UI/IDE possible to run in a [CI/CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) (continuous integration/delivery) system in collaborative environment where many code versions need to be merged and tested.

Do such setups exist already?

Comment: The Arduino itself is usually only a tiny portion of a project. The rest is other devices and sensors which interact in a "real world" way. Such things can not always be reliably simulated. Sure, you could run an AVR emulator, but what do you do about that ultrasound detector? How do you know that the motor is spinning right? What do you do when the device you want to use isn't even simulated at all?

Comment: Please close this question as accepted as you have already the next one -this is not a forum but one question at a topic knowledge base

Comment: I am not sure it's mandatory to accept a question with just 1 answer; the comment by Majenko does contain valuable information, too. My following question addresses another aspect of the knowledge base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems with this kind of software is:

- always behind the recent releases of cores/ hw variations.
- reliable only for simple programs/tasks
- Imho all the products I tested (mainly on Win) are actually a (somewhat crippled ) teaching and visualization help.
- if you look into the emulators you mostly see only support for different chips and not the whole micro computer, which is far more complex to create

Due to the low cost of the hardware it is easier to run real HW setups with HW diagnostics (and get also feedback for thermal/electric issues) 
So this kind of SW is for the low cost avr/esp HW and its hundreds of variants (even between production batches from one manufacturer) hard to develop and mantain. So you'll only find nice "play around" emulators which won't fulfill any professional requirement (even if some claim it)