# Can I integrate Arduino in a CI/CD setup?

Tags: automatization

While it seems [less valuable](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/74772/can-i-emulate-arduino-in-a-headless-ci-cd-setup?noredirect=1#comment162856_74772) to emulate Arduino in a CI/CD setup, are there any experiences/best practices for collaborative teams to automate their acceptance tests where a real Arduino is integrated into a CI/CD toolchain (or, what are comparable practices)?

Minimal example of acceptance testing:

- compilation is successful for a given compiler version.

Comment: Step one: Define what acceptance means in your project workflow.

Comment: added a minimal example.

Comment: For that: run arduino-builder in a script run by a cron job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different approaches around. I can only point you to some of them:

- [GitLab CI approach A](https://codeblog.dotsandbrackets.com/gitlab-ci-esp32-arduino/)
- [GitLab CI approach B](https://dzone.com/articles/hands-on-iot-devops-day-3-gitlab-cicd)
- Your specific solution: To build [pipelines for Arduino](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/azure-devops-build-pipelines-for-arduino-microcontrollers/) (although its Azure) but you can use this technique on [Linux with Jenkins](https://opensource.com/article/19/9/intro-building-cicd-pipelines-jenkins)

As a valuable commenter mentioned on your previous question - this does not cover the attached hardware testing (sensors/ motors) - this has to be "integrated" via a test lab station, which you have to control manually (or semi-automated via lab equipment) on defined release/version changes

Comment: thank you so much @Codebreaker007! Trying out approach A to compile the controller code for an open source ventilator project :-)