# How to install a dependency library to an Arduino compilation environment?

Tags: library, arduino-makefile

Following *[approach A](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/74781/can-i-integrate-arduino-in-a-ci-cd-setup)* from this Arduino SE answer, I managed to kick off an Arduino CLI compilation in a Docker environment.

However, the project I am trying to compile has a [dependency](https://github.com/mathertel/LiquidCrystal_PCF8574/tree/master/src) on a LCD control library.

Error output:

```
...../OpenSourceVentilator/OpenSourceVentilator.ino:494:116: 
fatal error: LiquidCrystal_PCF8574.h: 
No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

What is the proper way to link dependencies to the compilation environment of an Arduino project?

While the source suggests a direct compiler call, maybe I need a Makefile instead of the following?

```
arduino-cli compile --fqbn esp32:esp32:esp32 -o ignored.bin OpenSourceVentilator.ino
```

Comment: The tutorial, that you linked to as approach A from the other question, also has a part, which explains how to install extra libraries

Comment: @chrisl is that also an "Arduino-like" way or is there a more standard approach/package manager?

Comment: Why do you expect a non-Arduino like or more standard approach, when using the Arduino CLI?

Comment: I just wonder there is no management for external libraries Golang-style, but maybe it's even good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the library is installed the Arduino IDE (or CLI I assume too) just finds it and compiles/links it for you.

Comment: so what activities does installation of a library include if the library is on GitHub?

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/guide/libraries