# Arduino emulator to create virtual 3d printer farm

Tags: arduino-mega, emulation

I'm building a system to monitor several 3d printers, but I just have 1 printer. I'm thinking if there is any opensource tool to launch several virtual Arduino based boards running with Marlin firmware to accomplish my task. I'm planning to use Ocoprint for monitoring every board, so I need one serial port to communicate with the virtual printer.

I already modified the firmware in such a way that it runs on a clean ArduinoMEGA (without any shield) and it worked as I need.

I check the suggestions on [this related thread](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/61/can-i-program-for-arduino-without-having-a-real-board) but I'm not sure if any of them will work as I need.

Comment: Have you tried any of them? I would say it would be a far fetch to think, that any of them can really run the Marlin firmware (which is rather complex). Though you only need idle serial communication, so it might work. You should really try it first, because it is very difficult and complex to answer this. To write an answer without trying it, we would need to know the Marlin firmware and the simulators (not emulators) in detail, with all their requirements and caveats. It is just easier to try it first.

Comment: @chrisl I have tried the simulide, simavr, simultron none of them give an answer for serial communicaction